# Feature shape mismatch after dropping features during feature selection on test set (holdout set)

Tags: python

I have split my data (train.tsv) into 2 sets (Train & Validation sets), i.e., X_train, y_train, X_validation, y_validation.

After feature selection, I have dropped off 6 features. After dropping the features:

```
X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_validation.shape, y_validation.shape, X_test.shape
```

returns:

> ((59372, 40), (59372,), (14844, 40), (14844,), (10618, 46))

After fitting my model on X_train & y_train, I have predicted my model on X_validation.

But I also want to predict my model on a separate holdout set (test.tsv) using

```
y_pred_on_testset = model.predict(X_test)
```

This holdout set is essentially unseen data which I did not train my model on. However this holdout set has 46 features (as seen above from X_test.shape).

Does it make sense if I also drop the 6 features on this test.tsv (test set)? I know for sure I can predict my model on this test set after I drop the 6 features, else it will return an error:

> ValueError: Feature shape mismatch, expected: 40, got 46

**because I trained my model on 40 features, not 46**.

I'm not sure if I should proceed to drop the 6 features? As the test set is unseen data which I shouldn't be modifying?

Any advise is very much appreciated, thanks!